# How to publish a ASP.NET MVC 2 page in IIS 7?

Tags: c#, iis-7

I have an ASP MVC 2 page that works perfectly using the development server that comes with visual studio 2010, but all my attempts to publish it in a server (windows 2008) resulted in fail so far. I googled it various times, but none of the tutorials solved my problem. There's some errors, not just one:

- When I run the silverlight test page (an asp page that comes with the project) the parser complains of my mvc include in web.config. Following a tutorial I transfered the dlls to the bin folder, which resulted in ... nothing.
- Anyway I try to run my MVC page, an error message comes to my screen.

What should I do to have this page working?

Comment: Please post the error messages.

Comment: Please include all error messages, as a programmer you should know how important it is to know exactly whats happening.

Comment: What are the errors specifically?\

Comment: what's the error message? Is the application running in an app pool in integrated or classic mode?

Comment: It is running in integrated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as that MVC was not installed, and it took me a while to figure out that it was necessary. Also, the person who deals with the IIS set the wrong folder to be a Web Application. Thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to put my first website online I had the same problem. It runs perfectly on the test but not in IIS 7.

My mistake was that I forgot a \ at the and of the Physical path in IIS 7.

Don't know if you have the same problem, but you can check it.